# Try catch in R for SQL statement

Tags: r

all,

i am trying to put try catch for Sql statement in R. When it is successful, it should return Success or else failure. I tried to code it but was not successful. Can anyone help me .....

```
tryCatch({
sqlQuery(SQL, "exec [XXX].[CCC].[TABLEEEEE]", errors = FALSE)
},
error = function(err) showNotification("Success"))
```

i tried with below also but did not work

```
expr = {
sqlQuery(SQL, "exec [XXX].[CCC].[TABLEEEE]")
},
error = function(e){ 
"Error"
}
)
```

can anyone help me please.........

Answer (score 1):

Did you miss braces?

```
    tryCatch({
sqlQuery(SQL, "exec [XXX].[CCC].[TABLEEEEE]", errors = FALSE)
},
error = function(err) {showNotification("Success")})
```

Follow this and check which code runs,

```
tryCatch(
expr = {
    # Your code...
    # goes here...
    # ...
},
error = function(e){ 
    # (Optional)
    # Do this if an error is caught...
},
warning = function(w){
    # (Optional)
    # Do this if an warning is caught...
},
finally = {
    # (Optional)
    # Do this at the end before quitting the tryCatch structure...
}
)
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried but did not work.   Please refer my edited question

Comment: Okay which block ran?

Comment: If it is successful, it is not showing as succes and in case if it is failure . It is not showing as error only.